# MS Access Macro ApplyFilter Where Condition to include a OrderBy option

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to include an OrderBy option to my Where Condition string to order my records in descending date order. `PersOrgSubject` is a field, `tDate` is my date field, `FrmBMcRecord` is the name of my form and `Combo52` is my Combobox. So far this is my Where Condition......

Where Condition `=[PersOrgSubject]=[Forms]![FrmBMcRecord]![Combo52]`

Comment: Looks like macro code. Can't include sort criteria in that parameter. Apply sort condition to form OrderBy property. Macro has SetOrderBy action.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute two commands. One is for filtering and another for sorting. So, if you run command via macro then follow below macro commands.

[image]

If you want to do by `VBA` then try below codes-

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[PersOrgSubject]='" & [Forms]![FrmBMcRecord]![Combo52] & "'"
DoCmd.SetOrderBy "[tDate] DESC"
```